# custom walker nav issue involving ajax

Tags: menus, ajax

I am using ajax in a theme not written by me. This ajax gets the link clicked and then slides that page into view. it works good. In order for it to do it's thing, I had to make a custom walker for wp_nav_menu that adds two characters to the link so my links look like this in the nav

```
 http://my-site.com/#!/post-1
```

my problem with this is that when viewing a single page. I have to have WordPress reload the page to get the single post. So then my link would look like this

```
 http://my-site.com/?p=post-1
```

So when I hover over the nav to go back to a previous or new page, this is where my problem starts. my nav shows this as the selection when clicked

```
 http://my-site.com/?p=post-1#!/post-1
```

I don't know why it won't get rid of the previous address. Here is my custom walker
http://pastebin.com/Xn7NRiG7

Most of the site is is loading posts and pages into the index and then using the ajax to scroll that page into view. I am trying to make the single blog pages external to the ajax functionality. I tried using two different menus for this like so

```
 if( is_home() || is_page()){
           $args = array( 'depth' => 3, 'container' => '', 'container_class' => '','menu_class' =>'', 'menu_id' => 'menu', 'fallback_cb' => 'default_menu','link_before' => '<span></span><strong>','link_after' => '</strong>', 'theme_location' => 'primary','walker' => new Amaranthe_Custom_Walker_Nav_Sub_Menu());
            wp_nav_menu($args);
        } else {
           $args = array( 'depth' => 3, 'container' => '', 'container_class' => '','menu_class' =>'', 'menu_id' => 'menu', 'fallback_cb' => 'default_menu','link_before' => '<span></span><strong>','link_after' => '</strong>', 'theme_location' => 'primary');
            wp_nav_menu($args);
        } ?>
```

Do you have any idea how I might be able to get back into the ajax flow properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding this code to my walker

```
    if( !is_home()){
    $item->url = get_bloginfo('url')."/#!/page_".$temp_url;
}
```